# Compute P(n+1) given P(0)...P(n) for a polynomial P(n)

Tags: polynomials

A polynomial $P_{n}(n)$ of degree $n$ is defined by values $P(0)...P(n)$. How to compute $P(n+1)$?

*N.B.* Obvious solution is to solve the system of equations:

$c_nn^n + c_{n-1}n^{n-1}+...+c_0 = P(n)$

$c_n(n-1)^n + c_{n-1}(n-1)^{n-1}+...+c_0 = P(n)$

$...$

$c_n2^n + c_{2}n^{n-1}+...+c_0 = P(2)$

$c_n1^n + c_{1}n^{n-1}+...+c_0 = P(1)$

$c_0 = P(0)$

And then compute P(n+1) knowing the polynomial coefficients. But it would be prohibitively expensive from the computational P.O.V. — $O(n^3)$ complexity.

Looking for a nice mathematical solution of how to compute $P(n+1)$ through $P(0)...P(n)$.

**Update.** If using lagrange polynomial, after simplification:

$l_0 = (-1)^n$

$l_{i} = L_{i-1} * \frac{n - i -2}{i (-1)}$

$P(n + 1) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{l(i)P(i)}$

*N.B.* $l_i$ coefficients are fixed at $n+1$ for polynomial $P_n$. Generic solution for $P(n + k)$ is out of scope for this formula.

**Update 2.** Will give it a try using *method of finite differences*.

**Update 3.** Method of finite differences provides much simpler solution to the problem. First you have to compute matrix of differences:

$P_5(x) = 7x^4-48x^3-9x^2+0x^1-23$

```
[[  -23,   -73,  -331,  -833, -1447, -1873,     0],
 [  -50,  -258,  -502,  -614,  -426,     0,     0],
 [ -208,  -244,  -112,   188,     0,     0,     0],
 [  -36,   132,   300,     0,     0,     0,     0],
 [  168,   168,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
 [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0]]
```

Then you just backtrack from the bottom-most row and fill cells parallel to the antidiagonal:

```
[[  -23,   -73,  -331,  -833, -1447, -1873, -1643],
 [  -50,  -258,  -502,  -614,  -426,   230,     0],
 [ -208,  -244,  -112,   188,   656,     0,     0],
 [  -36,   132,   300,   468,     0,     0,     0],
 [  168,   168,   168,     0,     0,     0,     0],
 [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0]]
```

The right-most element of the first row is $P(6)$.

**N.B.** From the computational P.O.V. it requires $O(n^2)$ operations to compute either $P(n + 1)$ or $P(n + 1)...P(2n)$.

Using lagrange polynomial it could be done in $O(n)$ for a single $P(n+1)$ value, which could be beneficial if only the value at $P(n+1)$ is required.

Comment: The simplest is Newton's method of finite differences. There is a simple example on [the wikipedia page on the Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine#Method_of_differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with Lagrange interpolation?
Just put $n+1$ for $x$ into the big polynomial here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial and you are done. 
Furthermore, you can also simplify it, knowing that your positions are $0,...,n$. Then the polynomial $l_j$ will be
$$l_j = \frac{\prod_{m = 0}^n n+1 - m}{\prod_{m=0, m \neq j}^n j-m}$$
The top part is $(n+1)!$, the bottom part is $(-1)^{n-j} j!(n-j)!$.
Thus doing some more simplifications here, it should be rather efficient to compute it.
Note that I did not yet put in any values $P(i)$, so everything up to this point works for all such polynomials.

Comment: Love math for such nice tricks! Thanks.